# Running Magento on PHP 5.3 - Is it a BIG security concern?

Tags: magento-1.7

Earlier Magento versions 1.6-1.8 officially only support php version 5.4.

Given that Magento store is patched, is it a BIG security risk of running php 5.3 or 5.4? 
I personally, never heard sites being hacked due to outdated php version. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: There is no security risk, but it’s an good think for the optimisation of running if magento instance. There is a lot of article about that in internet

Comment: I do realize latest php offers much faster and optimize site reponse. But some mention there is a secuirty risk running PHP 5.3 version, aka website can get compromised...